# pass a DOM object to the handler of the oncomplete event?

Tags: ajax, jquery, primefaces

how to pass a DOM object (an input) to the handler of the oncomplete event so I can manipulate it's parent?

JSF code:

```
<p:datatable>
...
<p:column>

<h:inputText id="my_field" value="#{bean.my_field}">
    <p:ajax oncomplete="handle_oncomplete( $(this) )" listener="#{bean.handle_change}" />
</h:inputText>

</p:column>
...
</p:datatable>
```

JS code:

```
//NOT WORKING
function handle_oncomplete(my_param) {
  _parent = my_param.parent();                 
  _parent.css( "background", "#123456");
}
```

I used my_param.attr('source') to access the DOM object passed:

```
//WORKING
function handle_oncomplete(my_param) {
  _parent = $(my_param.attr('source')).parent();                 
  _parent.css( "background", "#123456");
}
```

Is there any other way?

**EDIT:** console.log(my_param.parent()) output

[image]

**EDIT:** Add code to reproduce the issue

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<f:view contentType="text/html" locale="fr" encoding="UTF-8">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="dvForm">
        <div id="my_id" style="padding: 50px;">
            <h:inputText id="my_input">
                <p:ajax update="" oncomplete="complete_handler($(this) )"
                    listener="#{bean.handle_change}" />
            </h:inputText>
        </div>
    </h:form>
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function complete_handler(my_param) {
             my_obj = my_param.attr('source');
             _parent = my_obj.parent();                 
             _parent.css( "background-color", "#123456");
        }
    </script>
</h:body>
```

**EDIT:** the generated html code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
href="/myproject/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-aristo" /><script 
type="text/javascript" 
src="/myproject/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml;jsessionid=5DDDEBBC02044818081D23A267940E72?ln=primefaces">
</script><script
type="text/javascript"
src="/myproject/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml;jsessionid=5DDDEBBC02044818081D23A267940E72?ln=primefaces">
</script></head><body>
<form id="dvForm" name="dvForm" method="post" 
action="/myproject/test/t1.xhtml;jsessionid=5DDDEBBC02044818081D23A267940E72"
enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="dvForm" value="dvForm" />
<div id="my_id" style="padding: 50px;"><input id="dvForm:my_input" type="text" 
name="dvForm:my_input"            onchange="PrimeFaces.ab({source:this,event:'valueChange',process:'dvForm:my_input',oncomplete:function(xhr,status,args){complete_handler($(this) );}},
arguments[1]);" /></div><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" 
id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="5837380100056002382:-3836335094805954101" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function complete_handler(my_input) {
    my_obj = my_input.attr('source');
    $(my_obj).parent().css('background-color', "#123456");
}
</script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `console.log( my_param.parent() );` (in the faulty function) say? It's weird that a bind to find a parent based on an attribute works.

Comment: @Allendar the source attribute of my_param refer to an input object: source=input#my_form:my_field

Comment: Maybe it works different in the structure you use. I've tested it in normal HTML DOM and doesn't give any error. Maybe you can check in the docs if the way your markup uses the tags is different (the way the parser works). The selector seems to be fine as it's outputted.

Comment: @Allendar I added a full page code to reproduce the issue. When I try to manipulate the object directly (without using attr('source')) I get no error but It does not work

Comment: That's not the code the browser sees. Forget about your JSF code and do a View Source in the browser and post that code instead.

Comment: @MichaelGeary I added the generated html code